# Daredevil comic in which he is visited by aliens that look like humans from the 19th century

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, aliens, daredevil

I think it may be from around 1970 but I haven't found any comic book covers that look like this story.

A group of some aliens (may be three) pay Daredevil a visit. Their spaceship looks like an aircraft from Jules Verne's novel "The Master of the World": an iron ship with many vertical propellers. The aliens look like Victorian gentlemen.

[image: Aircraft from the 1961 film based on the Verne novel]

They tell of having travelled for a hundred years to reach Earth. It is implied that their anachronistic appearance is the result of this delay. They ask Daredevil for some kind of help, I don't remember what. It is later discovered that their true appearance is some sort of giant mantis-like insects.

Comment: Could it be Daredevil #28 from 1967 where he encounters the “mantis-like” Queega? https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Daredevil_Vol_1_28 Not sure if they can shape-change or project false images/impressions. It’s not like Daredevil is a big galactic superhero that encounters that many different aliens.

Comment: If their appearance was just an illusion, would Daredevil even *see* it?

Comment: Depends on how those illusions work, but yes, if it is an illusion by implanting a false image telepatically it surely works similar to "normal" humans. If it works by altering the emmited light or bending it in some way, than surely the same would be possible with sound and maybe smells or whatever helps Daredevil identify species.